# How to check a class for a certain value and then return a result through Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

1: What I want to do is check if a page contains a specific class with a specific string, and if it does, send an event to Google Tag Manager.

2: I also need a macro to check if a certain element exists on a page and if it does, fire the tag above.

What I have been able to get together so far is the supposed tag:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
...
<a class="myClass">Captured value</a>
...
</body>
</html>
```

My tag to be fired using JavaScript would look something like this:

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0].innerHTML;
if (x.match ("Captured value")) {
dataLayer.push({'event':'captured'});
}
</script>
```

So this tag will fire if it sees the above anchor with that specific class. Using the above code though, I keep getting errors:

```
Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined(anonymous function) 
@VM490:2InjectedScript._evaluateOn 
@VM479:883InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap 
@VM479:816InjectedScript.evaluate 
@VM479:682
```

How would I write a cleaner code to not generate an error if the class doesn't exist?

Regarding number two, how would I write a function with a return statement? I just can't figure this one out. I have tried something along the lines of:

```
function () {
var t = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0].innerHTML;
var y = dataLayer.push({'event':'trigger'})
if (t.match ("Captured value")) {
return y;
}
```

I want to use a macro to check if the class exists on a page with the correct value, which in turn I can use as a trigger to fire the first tag. To use macros in GTM, I need to return a value. I just can't figure out how to check for the class value and have my tag fire upon its validation.

Another way to go is of course to write a custom HTML tag to fire on all pages and have the JavaScript look for, validate and send the event. I currently do not possess the JavaScript aptitude to figure out how that would look though.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: What type of tag are you using to check the page and when are you firing those tags? You should use custom HTML firing when event equals gtm.dom.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I am planning to fire the custom HTML tag on gtm.dom along with the macro that triggers the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach was all backwards. I attempted to use a JavaScript solution while I could just use a custom JS inside of Tag Manager to check for a defined value and fire a trigger if it resolved to true.

The methodology I was thinking about was about right I guess, but the way about doing it was over complicating things.

What I did was add a custom JavaScript macro named cjs.return class (using v1 for this said container) and added the following code:

```
function (){
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0].innerHTML;
    return x;
}
```

This function returned either undefined or "Captured value" depending on if it was the right page or not. I then set up a new rule to trigger my tag if:

- event equals gtm.dom
- cjs.return class equals Captured value

This new rule triggered my tag, which in turn could send the data on the specific set of pages I wanted it to fire on.

Thanks to both Eike and nyuen for answering to give me a clearer picture of what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

With your second block of code, I would first make it a self-invoking function

```
<script>
(function(){
   ...
}()
</script>
```

that checkes for the presence of the class in question and also checks for the required text. Use 'indexOf' rather than 'matches' (so you do not need to deal with regex).  If those two conditions are true, then push your event to the dataLayer. Fire this tag when event equals gtm.dom, along with any other conditions you think should apply, and that should do it.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I now know how to self-invoke a function! :) Also, using indexOf would probably be a better.

Answer (score 1):

Google Tag Manager has a perfectly usable DOM element variable for this. Go to variables (assuming GTM v2), "new", "DOM Element", Selection Method "CSS selector", selector ".myClass" (from your example).

Set up a trigger "page view", trigger type "DOM ready", fire on "yourDOMelement eq. "Captured value".

Unless I misunderstand your needs you should not havbe to write any custom javascript.

Comment: Great feedback. Unfortunately they aren't running v2 as of yet, so I cannot use the CSS Selector at the moment. v1 only uses ID as far as I know, and since the value I am trying to trigger on isn't an ID but a class, I didn't think I could use it.